# Replacement Strip of Siding

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

When I purchased my house I noticed a strip of siding assumingly blew off the garage.  In the garage was a strip of siding that was the correct length to replace it.  I tried going up there and fitting it into place to no avail, the new strip is too tall by about an inch.  Do I have the wrong siding or do I need to do something to get these to fit together.  I am a total newbie to siding.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jhi1618 already noted, since you have a new piece of siding (new as in it has the snap channel and nailing strip on the top of it if new) it will need to be trimmed to fit.  You'll notice that there's a stop strip that runs across the top of the wall where it meets the soffit - this is to hold the last course of siding in place because you'll be cutting off the nailing strip. The siding piece needs to be cut so that it snaps all the way into the snap channel on the piece below it and all the way to the top of the stop strip.

On new installations I'll take a short cutoff or scrap of siding and direct mark for transfer to the piece I'm cutting, but this is usually difficult to impossible after the soffit is already up. In your case, the best route will likely be a tape measure. You'll want to measure in multiple spots for a run that long (each end and about every 4 feet), because even on the best siding jobs it is unlikely that it will be perfectly straight and level.  When you make the cut, err on the side of too long and trim as needed.

After you are happy with the test fit, you need to do what the previous installer likely forgot or neglected to do based on the fact that the last piece blew off.  You'll need to punch the top of the cut siding so that it will snap into the stop channel, since there isn't a good way to nail that doesn't look like absolute hell. Buy, rent, beg, or borrow a [snap lock punch](http://mrotools.com/wslp1-wiss-snap-lock-punch-vinyl-aluminum-siding-and-plastic-skirting.aspx)<sup>1</sup> and punch the top of the cut siding every 16 inches or so. This is what will hold it in place, as it prevents it from backing out of the stop strip and loosening from the snap channel on the piece below it.  While you're up there, I'd check the other pieces and punch them as well if they're just floating in the stop strip.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The link provided is intended solely to demonstrate the proper type of tool to use and does not constitute a recommendation or endorsement for the brand, model, or vendor.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

With vinyl siding, you start at the bottom and work up, so when you get to the top, you're left with a piece that probably needs to be cut.  You try to measure before you start so you have close-to-a-full-piece at the top, which is what seems to be the case here.  I'm guessing you found a new piece in the garage that would need to be trimmed a little.

Look at how much the existing top piece seems to be cut, and how the top is fastened into place so you don't cut the new piece incorrectly.  You might be able to pull on the edge of the existing piece to get a better idea of how it's being held in place.